# Can't login to round cube new domain

Tags: email-server, ubuntu-12.04, imap, roundcube

I have multiple mail domains boxes on my mail server, and all are working normally,

I configured new mail domain "example.ae" normally on mysql mail db, and the domain's inbox was created on server,

But when i tried to login to my account on the new mail on roundcube, i got the error "login connection to storage server failed"

Round cube's logs were:

```
[01-Feb-2016 23:00:01 +0200]: IMAP Error: Login failed for myaccount@example.ae from 2.2.2.2. Could not connect to newdomain.ae:143: Connection refused in /var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

**Note:** the application server is separated and hosted on another different server under domain "example.ae", i have no idea why roundcube is trying to imap connect with the app server!

Comment: Could you add the $config['default_host'] of roundcube ?

Comment: That was the issue, the default values made round cube trying to resolve the "newdomain.ae" to the app server not the mail server, please check my answer below,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally fixed it,
Round cube default configuration was resolving the @newdomain.ae to the app server not the mail server,

I modified the host parameter for both smtp and imap in the roundcube configuration file "`config/main.inc.php`" `$rcmail_config['smtp_server']` and `$rcmail_config['default_host']` to the mail server IP, and it finally worked :)